# Start the GUI automatically in OpenBSD

Tags: gnome, x11, openbsd, startup

I can't find the GUI to start up automatically in OpenBSD hppa 5.3. What commands must I use to get this working?
I want to use Gnome like in OpenSuse which I am more comfortable with.

Comment: HPPA? what kind of video card are you using? You must know that not all PARISC video cards are supported for running X in either Linux or BSD.

Comment: its hp fxe it should run X i think,but it wont

Answer (score 1):

[OpenBSD doesn't have X support on HPPA.](http://www.openbsd.org/hppa.html)

Comment: ok what should i consider than,use a different gui or another solution ?

Comment: If X isn't supported at all, then GUI isn't an option.

Comment: Ok I understand,so i dont have to try and find a way to bypass this..